# PHP Code not working inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
echo "Value: " .$_GET['val']. "<script>document.write('<?php echo 'It does not work!'; ?>'); </script>";?>
```

above code inside javascript is not giving output while the below code is working well, what am i missing withing the above code?

```
<script>document.write('<?php echo 'It works!'; ?>'); </script>
```

Comment: You are not closing your first php tag so php sees the second <? Php said normal text

Comment: already did it! yet not working @melvin

Comment: <?php echo "Value: " .$_GET['val']. "<script>document.write('$whatever''); </script>";?>  where whatever is a var with the text you want

Comment: This should be working,

<?php
$text='It's working!';
echo "Value: " .$_GET['val']. "<script>document.write("'.$text.'"); </script>";
?>

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to open 'php' twice..

or 'echo' twice..

So that just leaves having matching sets of quotes in the correct sequence.

```
echo "Value: " .$_GET['val']. "<script>document.write('It does work!'); </script>";
     ^.......^                ^--------------------------------------------------^
                                                      ^-------------^
```